# How to request that I be allowed to share some pages from someone else's newspaper

Tags: phrase-request

I am on the way to office in a bus/train and someone seated nearby is reading a newspaper. I would like to ask him/her to share few pages of his/her newspaper. Could someone give me some polite English sentences for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably ask for specific sections (that they're not reading):

> "Do you mind if I read the/your sports section?"
>
> "Are you done with the front page? (If so, can I please borrow it?)"
>
> "Do you mind if I check today's weather?"